# How could I add a search on an embed SoundCloud player?

Tags: php, javascript, soundcloud

I am writing a SoundCloud player for my website. I want to know whether I can search songs using the SoundCloud API [previewed here](http://codecanyon.net/item/soundcloud-search-api-integration/full_screen_preview/3378704).

Please share any other references or samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soundcloud API endpoints for you:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks

If have created a little fiddle here to demo how you can use the SC JS SDK.

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/2AMen/

```
 SC.initialize({
    client_id: "201b55a1a1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  //  redirect_uri: "http://example.com/callback.html",
  });

SC.get("/tracks", {limit: 10, genres: "jazz"}, function(tracks){
        var length = tracks.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
            $('#results').append(tracks[i].genre + ' | ' + tracks[i].permalink_url + '<br/>');
    }
});
```

Your example looks like that its implemented using a php backend.

So thats the right SDK for you:

https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud

Thats an php example using this SDK:

```
   <?php
include 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

$soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud('yourClientId', 'yourClientSecret', 'yourRedirectUri');

try {
    $tracks = json_decode($soundcloud->get('tracks', array('genres' => 'jazz', 'limit' => '10')));
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
print_r($tracks);
?>
```